# Entity relationship diagram

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

I am trying to create an entity relationship model for my application.

The application has questions and answers within a quiz.

The model which I have produced so far looks like this:

[image]

I am quite new to these diagrams, so would appreciate if someone could explain how to complete it with an arrow and multiplicity.

The Quiz table holds questions in QUIZ_TEXT and the correct answer in CORRECT_ANSWER

The Answer table holds the answers in ANSWERS and matches these answers with the QUIZ_ID which is the question.

I understand this is probably simple but I haven't worked with databases for a long time and my mind is going blank. Also all I need to do is this then I can move on and the majority of my work is not on databases. Please help. Thanks

Edit:

I have tried to do this, please let me know if this is correct. Thanks: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between Quiz and Answer is one-to-many so you should draw line from Quiz to Answer and put a crow's foot in the Answer end. There are other notations but this is one of the most common ways.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please can you tell me if I need to add any writing within the arrow. Also would this be complete, would I need to add anything else? Thanks.

Comment: It looks good. If you want you can add more detail by telling the specifics of the relation. See this link: http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/7474 and on that page "summary of crow's foot notation". You could use the "one or many" type of symbol in your diagram.